# Is it possible to send div as email template in Django

Tags: django

I'm Django newbie.
I wonder if anybody tried to do that.
I have UpdateView that renders update form as div and some other content as another div. I wonder if you could send that another div as an e-mail message. I would be like ordering shipping with pickup and delivery address.
Does it make sense anyway?

views.py

```
class VCIUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = VCI
    context_object_name = 'VCIUpdate'
    form_class = VCIModelForm
    template_name = 'VCIupdate.html'
    success_url = "/VCI"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(VCIUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['subsidiary_address'] = Subsidiary.objects.all()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs ):
        context = super(VCIUpdateView, self).get_context_data()
        send_mail("hello", context, 'email', ['email@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
        return super(VCIUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

VCIUpdate.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-4">
    <div class="col">
      <form method="post" id="subsidiaryForm"  name="text" data-subsidiaries-url="{% url 'ajax_load_subsiriaies' %}" data-salesPersonsDistributor-url="{% url 'ajax_load_salesPersonsDistributor' %}" data-salesPersonsDistributorContact-url="{% url 'ajax_load_salesPersonsDistributorContact' %}" novalidate>
        <table class="table table-borderless table-condensed">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
       <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row" id="text">
        <table class="table table-borderless">
          <thead>
            <th>Adres odbioru:</th>
            <th></th>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Filia:</th>
              <td>{{ VCIUpdate }}
              <td>{{ VCIUpdate.salesPersonDistributor.subsidiary }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Kontakt:</th>
              <td>{{ VCIUpdate.salesPersonDistributor.name }} {{ VCIUpdate.salesPersonDistributor.surname }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Telefon:</th>
              <td>{{ VCIUpdate.salesPersonDistributor.phone }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Kontakt:</th>
              <td>{{ VCIUpdate.salesPersonDistributor.email }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Ulica:</th>
              <td>{{ VCIUpdate.salesPersonDistributor.subsidiary.street }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Miasto:</th>
              <td>{{ VCIUpdate.salesPersonDistributor.subsidiary.city }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Kod pocztowy:</th>
              <td>{{ VCIUpdate.salesPersonDistributor.subsidiary.postal }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="salesPersonsDistributorContact">
      </div>
      <div class="row" id='address' data-subsidiaryAddressDelivery-url="{% url 'ajax_load_subsidiaryAddressDelivery' %}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <script>
// with page load hide some content
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
     $("#subsidiaryForm").show();
     $('#id_subsidiary').hide();
     $("label[for='id_subsidiary']").hide();

     $('#id_salesPersonDistributor').hide();
     $("label[for='id_salesPersonDistributor']").hide();
   }),

// load susidiary base on distrubutor
   $("#id_distributor").change(function () {
     var url = $("#subsidiaryForm").attr("data-subsidiaries-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
     var distributorId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

     $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
       url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
       data: {
         'distributor': distributorId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
       },
       success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
         $("#id_subsidiary").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
         $("#id_salesPersonDistributor").html('');
         $('#id_subsidiary').show();
         $("label[for='id_subsidiary']").show();
       }
     });

   });

//load sales force of subsidiary
   $("#id_subsidiary").change(function () {
     var url = $("#subsidiaryForm").attr("data-salesPersonsDistributor-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
     var subsidiaryId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input
     var url_address = $("#address").attr("data-subsidiaryAddressDelivery-url");

     $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
       url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
       data: {
         'subsidiary': subsidiaryId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
       },
       success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
         $("#id_salesPersonDistributor").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
         $('#id_salesPersonDistributor').show();
         $("label[for='id_salesPersonDistributor']").show();
       }
     });

// load subsidiary address
    $.ajax({
      url: url_address,
      data: {
          'subsidiary': subsidiaryId
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#address").html(data);
      }
    });
   });

// load sales person - distributor data
   $("#id_salesPersonDistributor").change(function () {
     var url = $("#subsidiaryForm").attr("data-salesPersonsDistributorContact-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
     var salesPersonDistributorId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

     $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
       url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
       data: {
         'salesPersonDistributor': salesPersonDistributorId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
       },
       success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
         $("#salesPersonsDistributorContact").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
       }
     });

   });
 </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You can create another template with just that div, pass it the same arguments and send the html via mail. Is that answering your question?

Comment: It looks that it is quite complex as div content is changing base on user input. Complex for me :d